# How to wait for a method that is already being executed?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I'm developing a Flutter app which has some tabs inside, each of them depend on the database that is loaded on the first run. State is stored in a ScopedModel.

On every tab I have this code:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  loadData();
}

void loadData() async {
    await MyModel.of(context).scopedLoadData();

    _onCall = MyModel.of(context).onCall;

    setState(() {

    });
  }
```

And this is the code snippet that matters for the ScopedModel:

```dart
Future<Null> scopedLoadData() async {

  if (_isLoading) return;

  _isLoading = true;

  (...)

  _isLoading = false;

}
```

If the user waits on the first tab for a few seconds everything is fine, since Database is loaded. However, if the user switches tabs right after app launch, the method **scopedLoadData** is still being executed so that I get a runtime error (*"Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'ancestorWidgetOfExactType' was called on null."*).

This exception happens because the **scopedLoadData** has not yet been completed. So I'm looking for a way to wait for a method that is still being executed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the exception by getting rid of every:

```
setState(() { });
```

and implementing *ScopedModelDescendant* on every relevant tab on top of using *notifyListeners()* at the end of the database loading method.

This pulls the responsibility from the tabs for updating views and gives it to the *scopedLoadData()*.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure without seeing your build method but I would start your build method with a guard clause.

```
if (_oncall == null) return Container(); // or Text("loading") or similar
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that then I get the Container() and still get the same exception. I found out that the exception is being caused by the setState() that is being called in **loadData()**. If I could call setState from inside the ScopedModel (when data is already loaded) it would be solved, but ScopedModel can't call setState since it doesn't extend State.

Answer (score 0):

use should be using a `FutureBuilder` on each tab to make sure the data is loaded before you try to build the widget... more code would be helpful